# Changing the font size of a label in a chart in javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2

Is there any way to modify the font used in chart lables in javafx 2?
Just to clarify the labels I'm referring to are the ones displayed after setting setLabelsVisible to true. There doesn't seem to be any way of modifying the font type or size through the api and I haven't found any css styles that do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean in a pie chart, use

```
.chart-pie-label {
  -fx-font-size: 10pt ;
}
```

in an external css file. See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#piechart